# How to hide Calendar after picking month in jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below code, how can I hide the calendar when I pick the month?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" id="div_monthly_cal" style="display:none;">
  <div data-date-minviewmode="months" data-date-viewmode="months" data-date-format="mm-yyyy" data-date="" class="input-append date dpMonths" id="dtpk2">
    <input name="month_pick" id="month_pick" type="text" value="<?php echo date('m-Y'); ?>" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
    <span class="input-group-btn add-on">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use `autoclose: true` property.

Comment: where to write it? i have written it in JQuery, but its not working.

Comment: What type of calendar do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery calendar, than you can use below code :-

```
$('#example1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {    
        $('#example1').Close();    
 });
```

**Update 1:**
You can also use the `autoclose` option, shown below :-

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',       
    autoclose: true        
});
```

**Update 2:** Another option

```
$('#dp1').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){                 
    $('#dp1').datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: I have put same code in JQuery function but its not working.

Comment: jQuery('#dtpk2').datepicker({
   autoclose: true ;
        });

Comment: yes both are not working.If i keep data-date-viewmode ='' its working, but its giving me dd-mm-yyyy format.  if I write data-date-viewmode ='months', its giving me month format but not working for autoclose.

Comment: I am using bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: please see Update 2 in answer

Comment: @Madhura please mark as answer if it helps, so other can use it.